What is the way of drinking chimarrao correctly and easily?
I love yerba and tried to taste a new one for me - chimarrao (Brazilian yerba, very fine, nearly flour). Having looked at some videos, I tried teabags on bombilla, preparing it properly and tapping on it slightly before I pour hot water. But.. nothing helps. Very difficult to sip.
From soil physics, I understand that the cause isn't that the straw (bombilla) gets clogged with yerba fine particles, but probably because drinking yerba is a process of seeping through the wet environment. The finer the particles are, the more difficult it is to seep.
So the only way is stirring it, but if you stir it, particles come to your mouth with water. That's not good. Also stirring and disrupting the continuity of the yerba environment is prohibited.
Who knows the truth and the way? Any Brazilians here maybe?

Welcome to the Site. Just to be clear, since you never mention it directly: Your issue is, that the yerba particles get into the water, creating some kind of sludge, I assume?

Yes, they mix with water and create a kind of sludge, so it's normally that seeping is difficult. Not so with common types of yerba, as particles are much coarser.  But somehow they drink it.
